# Closing as OT with custom reason: why not use the custom text in the close banner?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, vote-to-close

When voting to close a question as off topic, and entering a custom close reason, should not that text be used in the "closing banner" that is displayed in the post? Given that all close-voters use the same reason, of course.

This came up after [\lvert \rvert with unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366810) was closed. The banner looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the default text is used here. But I'm fairly sure all who voted to close used the reason entered by CarLaTeX, seen in [her comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366810/lvert-rvert-with-unicode-math?noredirect=1#comment904459_366810):

[image]

I was the fourth to cast a close vote, and the dialog indicated that the three before me had used the same, custom, reason. gernot also used this reason (I asked).

Can the banner be made to use the custom text, instead of the default "not in scope" text? Even if the custom text is added in a comment, I think it would be better if the banner used the same.